# Play only first 30 Seconds of the video HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I m trying to make my video play only the first 30 secs of the video and return to the starting time going as loop irrespective of video length.

Here's my code so far.

**HTML**

```
<video width="100%" height="192px" id="player" controls loop >
       <source src="images/videos/<?= $v_video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="images/videos/<?= $v_video; ?>" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    var playTimeout;    

$("#player").on("play", function(e) {
    playTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("player").pause();
        $("player").setCurrentTime(0); // Restarts video
    }, 30000); // 30 seconds in ms
});


$("#player").on("pause", function(e) {
    clearTimeout(playTimeout);
});
</script>
```

However, it stills keeps on playing after 30sec.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("player").pause();
$("player").setCurrentTime(0); // Restarts video
```

needs to be

```
$("#player").get(0).pause();
$("#player").get(0).currentTime = 0; // Restarts video
```

Also, I would use the `timeupdate` event so that the video doesn't reset while it is still loading (in your example, with a slow connection, if they spend 10 seconds buffering before playback, it would reset after only 20 seconds of playing).

See example (set to 3 seconds instead of 30 for easier demo):

```js
var playTimeout;    

$("#player").on("timeupdate", function(e) {
    playTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#player").get(0).pause();
        $("#player").get(0).currentTime = 0; // Restarts video
    }, 3000); // 3 seconds in ms
});


$("#player").on("pause", function(e) {
    clearTimeout(playTimeout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="player" controls="true" height="200" width="300">
  <source type="video/ogg" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.ogv">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4">
</video>
```